# PHP/JS Form doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in PHP who sends the information by e-mail, a classic form.
I want that cities can be selected only by department.
I have a code JQuery which I duplicate for every department:

```
$(".01").hide();
$('select[name=departement]').change(function(){
 var departement = $(this).val();
 if (departement== "01"){$("#ville, .01").show();}
  else {$(".01").hide();}
});
```

My part of the HTML form departments:

```
<select name="departement" id="departement" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">S&eacute;lectionnez votre D&eacute;partement</option>
                <option value="01" <?php if (isset($_POST['departement']) && $_POST['departement']== "01"){echo "selected";} ?>>01 - Ain</option>
</select>
```

The part City:

```
<div id="form_ville" class="form-group">
  <label>Nom de la ville*</label>
  <select id="ville" name="ville" class="form-control">
    <option value="-1">S&eacute;lectionnez votre ville</option>
          <option value="Belley" class="01" <?php if (isset($_POST['ville']) && $_POST['ville']== "Belley"){echo "selected";} ?>>Belley</option>
          <option value="Bourg-en-Bresse" class="01" <?php if (isset($_POST['ville']) && $_POST['ville']== "Bourg-en-Bresse"){echo "selected";} ?>>Bourg-en-Bresse</option>
          <option value="Nantua" class="01" <?php if (isset($_POST['ville']) && $_POST['ville']== "Nantua"){echo "selected";} ?>>Nantua</option>
          <option value="Gex" class="01" <?php if (isset($_POST['ville']) && $_POST['ville']== "Gex"){echo "selected";} ?>>Gex</option>
```

My problem is that the form works correctly under Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome but under IE quite cities are selectable from the beginning even without having chosen the department..

Thank you and good day to everybody!

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use ? Versions 2+ are not compatibles with old IE.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>